# "source_files must be set" coveralls php

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit, travis-ci, coveralls

I am trying to setup coveralls with Travis and I have a `source_files must be set` error

```
$ php coveralls.phar -v
Load coverage clover log:
  - /home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/build/logs/clover.xml
Collect git info
Read environment variables
source_files must be set

#0 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/src/Satooshi/Bundle/CoverallsV1Bundle/Entity/JsonFile.php(154): Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Entity\JsonFile->ensureJobs()
#1 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/src/Satooshi/Bundle/CoverallsV1Bundle/Api/Jobs.php(98): Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Entity\JsonFile->fillJobs(Array)
#2 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/src/Satooshi/Bundle/CoverallsV1Bundle/Repository/JobsRepository.php(123): Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Api\Jobs->collectEnvVars(Array)
#3 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/src/Satooshi/Bundle/CoverallsV1Bundle/Repository/JobsRepository.php(66): Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Repository\JobsRepository->collectEnvVars()
#4 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/src/Satooshi/Bundle/CoverallsV1Bundle/Command/CoverallsV1JobsCommand.php(161): Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Repository\JobsRepository->persist()
#5 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/src/Satooshi/Bundle/CoverallsV1Bundle/Command/CoverallsV1JobsCommand.php(114): Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Command\CoverallsV1JobsCommand->executeApi(Object(Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Config\Configuration))
#6 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(259): Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Command\CoverallsV1JobsCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(840): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(192): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Satooshi\Bundle\CoverallsV1Bundle\Command\CoverallsV1JobsCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(123): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 phar:///home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar/bin/coveralls(21): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#11 /home/travis/build/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/application/tests/coveralls.phar(12): require('phar:///home/tr...')
#12 {main}
```

The build is here https://travis-ci.org/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/builds/174537515 and the commit built is here https://github.com/Toolwatchapp/tw-backend/tree/1220893cdce17553ab98ffc28efd028108ec770c

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is likely that the `root_dir` is off

Judging from [this discussion](https://github.com/satooshi/php-coveralls/issues/92) this is the possible reason of the problem.

Try specifying the correct `root_dir` according to the [docs](https://github.com/satooshi/php-coveralls).